# Question about ERDAS TOC

Tags: erdas-imagine

On occasionally when I open a raster in ERDAS 2013, I get white or yellow circle icons on my ERDAS Contents and tried to find information on ERDAS.

I want to know what does the icon mean ? Thanks appreicate it.

Her is an attachment of what it looks like[image: Look I mark circle here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I got it. When there is a detect a problem, it display the icon next to the layer name and you just right click on the layer name and you see a green check that says "Correct the Alert Problem". Thanks.